# How do you switch from grease pencil mode to 3d mode/?

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

How do you switch from grease pencil mode to 3d mode/view? I did a drawing in grease pencil mode that I'd like to bring into 3D mode with the end goal of converting the strokes into a mesh but I do not know what key combination or steps to switch to 3D mode/view from grease pencil mode. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated. -Thanks

Comment: I've never used grease pencil but there seem to be plenty of answers on the web. If you click on the '+' (Add Workspace) icon to the right of the Rendering entry in the header bar and choose General > Modelling that should do the trick!

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't think about that thanks a lot John!